# reload ~/.tmux.conf

Tags: tmux

In ~/.tmux.conf, I use this `bind-key`

```
bind-key R source-file ~/.tmux.conf; display-message "~/.tmux.conf is reloaded"
```

but, when I use this tmux create  a new session.
why ?

#### Edit

this is the [complete file](https://github.com/juanpabloaj/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux.conf)

Comment: Do you create a new session in your `.tmux.conf`? It's sometimes recommended, so you can run `tmux attach` and have a new session created if there is no existing session to attach to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 15 of your `.tmux.conf`, "new bash", starts a new session, with "bash" as the command to run in its first window. "new" is an alias for "new-session".

Comment: how I can open a new session only the first time ?

Comment: When you start tmux, if you don't give it any command (either on the command line, or in the configuration file), it defaults to 'new-session'. You can just remove line 15. Then, I suggest starting `tmux` using `tmux a || tmux new`. This will attempt to connect to the (first, whatever that means) active session, and if it fails, create a new session.